# Intermittent Unfinished Stubbing Detected in Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

```
 class Mocktest {
    KafkaProducer kafkaProducer = Mockito.mock(KafkaProducer.class);

    @Test
    public void consumeRecordsTest() throws IOException {
        doCallRealMethod().when(this.kafkaProducer).publishMessage(any(BaseBizDTO.class));
        ArgumentCaptor<BaseBizDTO> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(BaseBizDTO.class);
        verify(this.kafkaProducer, atMost(2)).publishMessage(argument.capture());
        List<BaseBizDTO> values = argument.getAllValues();
    }
    
}


class KafkaProducer {
    public void publishMessage(BaseBizDTO dto) {}
}
```

Getting the following error on the above lines of code.

**Unfinished stubbing detected here:**

This is happening at doCallRealMethod() line

Comment: try please without 'this'. Otherway please provide more details. Need some code to play with.

Comment: @Feelfree Added more details in description itself. This is intermittent behaviour. Works fine on my local machine but when this is run by sonar cube integration, it gives error most of the time.

Comment: Did you try to create instance -> KafkaProducer kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer();
 maybe mocked object it`s not really what you need in this case

Comment: Where's your actual test code / what are you actually trying to test? You are only setting up your test doubles and then verify some calls. But you are never actually performing those calls. Where do you test your class? And what class _is_ your class under test? – all I can see is a test double, but no real production code.

Comment: Mocked object is required. I can't share the complete code for obvious reasons

Comment: @mohitsahu even without the "real" code, you should at least share a [mre]. Right now, your stubs are never called and there is nothing being tested. Consequently, the answer would currently be "write an actual test first instead of only setting up mock objects and then not doing anything with it"

Comment: @knittl I have some assertions on the values of BaseBizDTO. This issue is intermittent. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes it gives error.